# How to add the class instance to a class variable in dataclass notation?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

## I want to add all of the class instances to a class variable

I want to do this:

```
class Circle:
    all_circles = []
    def __init__(self, rad):
        self.rad = rad
        self.__class__.all_circles.append(self)
```

So when ever I make a new circle instance it is added to the `all_circle` class variable.

### How to do this in `dataclass` notation?

I wanted to replicate the code at the top in `@dataclass` but I couldn't find anywhere how to do this because I can't access the self.

Something like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar


@dataclass
class Circle:
    rad: int = 1
    all_circles = ClassVar[list] = [] # after this I don't know how to get the self because it is not available
```

But I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Found the answer

I found a solution after looking at other examples of the `dataclass`!
You can use the `__post_init__` function to achieve the same result!

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Circle:
    rad: int = 1
    all_circles = ClassVar[list["Circle"]] = []

    def __post_init__(self: "Circle") -> None:
        Circle.all_circles.append(self)
```

If there is a better way to do this please tell me.

Comment: note, both here and above you can use `self.all_circles.append(self)`

Comment: Yes, here I can but the problem with the code above was that I didn't know how to get the self to do this and then I found `__post_init__` function. Thanks for the suggestion though I didn't think about it that way!